# Twitter Bootstrap datepicker initial value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), but cant's seem to get it working properly.
Whem i click the datepicker it does not have the initial value of the date field it is attached to, but starts somewhere around 1920.

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/bootstrap.min.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/datepicker.css")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/bootstrap-datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="@value" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
      <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="@value"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the contents of `@value`? Can't reproduce this when `@value` is in the same format as the expected date format: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/5DWEJ/1/

Comment: The @value is due to this code being part of a Play Framework Scala template. Could this be the reason that it is not working?

Comment: If `@value` is not in the correct date format, this could cause you problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the working datepicker jsfiddle [Datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/7khwX/2/)

```
<div data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="19-02-2013" id="dp3"class="input-append date">
<input type="text" readonly="" value="19-02-2013" size="16" class="span2">  
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
```

set the `@value` to the date of your choice